# How to insert a current date of import when importing data from excel to access?

Tags: vb.net, excel, import

I had ask to insert a extra field of data (which will be the date of importing the excel data into access) along with original import excel data into access table.

Below is the code that importing the excel data into access. can any one please tell me what code need to write in order to insert the current date along with original excel data into access table after the docmd. transferspreadsheet.

```
   Dim objXL As New Excel.Application
   Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
   Dim wks As Object

   'objXL.Visible = True

   Set wkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

   For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
           "Plymouth - Nominal Detail", strFileName, True, wks.Name & "$"


   Next

   'Tidy up
   wkb.Close
   Set wkb = Nothing
   objXL.Quit
   Set objXL = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a temporary table in Access:

1. Generate a temporary table name
2. TransferSpreadsheet into the temporary table
3. Run an Access query that moves the contents of the temp table into your master table, along with the additional fields
4. Delete the temp table

The Access VBA code would look something like this before starting your 'For Each' loop...

```
' Use Now() function to create a semi-unique temporary table name in which to import
Dim strTempTableName as String
strTempTableName = "TempNominalDetail" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")

' This is the SQL code to copy contents of temp table into target table
' and add current date-time value.  Target table must already exist!

Dim strSQLCommand as String
strSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO [Plymouth - Nominal Detail] SELECT *, " & _
                   "NOW() as [DateTimeFieldName] FROM [" _
                   & strTempTableName & "];"
```

The `strSQLCommand` variable contains the command to append the contents of the temp table into your target table (Plymouth - Nominal Detail).  One key requirement is that the structure of the target table must match the structure of your source spreadsheet -- except the target table must have an additional field at the end that stores a date value.  In the code above I named it `DateTimeFieldName` but you can change that to some field name of your choosing, as long as it is at the end of the Plymouth - Nominal Detail table field list.

Inside the loop, replace the current DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet with these statements... (Notice that the boolean parameter in the original TransferSpreadsheet has been changed from True to **False**, because you want to throw away the prior table contents and start fresh each time.)

```
      ' Copy data into temp table, then transfer temp table into master table
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
           strTempTableName, strFileName, False, wks.Name & "$"
      DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLCommand
```

After the loop, as part of the cleanup, delete the temporary table.

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject(acTable, strTempTableName)
```

The temporary table is generated and then thrown away under the assumption that you might possibly have two or more simultaneous users of your database.  If you are certain that that will never be the case, you could define `strTempTableName` to just something simple like `"TempNominalDetail"` (without any fancy function to generate a unique name).

If you are considering going the route of temporary tables, there are some downsides.  Access is bad at reclaiming space used by deleted records or tables, so temp tables can cause your database to balloon quickly in size.  An occasional Database Compact operation will address that issue, but it's a noticeable one.  Also, the method I propose for generating a "unique" temporary file name is not guaranteed to work; if two different users start this process at exactly the same second, the function assigns them the same temp table name, and therefore their work will collide.

Comment: i got syntax error for insert SQL statement. strSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO Plymouth - Nominal Detail ([ImportDate]) SELECT *, NOW() FROM [" _
                       & strTempTableName & "];"

Comment: First -- make sure the brackets `[` and `]` enclose your target table name (Plymouth - Nominal Detail).  More importantly, I left an important part out of the SQL statement; the NOW() value needs to be given a name that matches the name of the last field in your `[Plymouth - Nominal Detail]` table.  I edited the answer to indicate that. Sorry for forgetting to note that in the original answer!

Answer (score 0):

The macro way would look something like this

RunMenuCommand: Import Attach Excel

OpenQuery: create an Update Query with is null value filter on date field and update value of `Now()`.

StopMacro